# OleDb through open file dialog in Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am using Visual Basic Express 2010.  Form 3 has code to import a csv file into a DataGridView while creating a DataSet.  This event happens when I open Form 3.  The path to the file is in the code.  I would like to have a button on Form 1 that opens an OpenFileDialog so the user can browse for the csv file.  Once the user selects the file, the DataGridView and DataSet on Form 3 initiate.  The code I am currently using is below.  Is there a way to edit the code to have an open file dialog from a button on Form 1 and not auto load through a pathway?  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
Public Class Form3

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim file As String = "test.csv"
        Dim path As String = "C:\Users\laptop\Desktop\"
        Dim ds As New DataSet

        End If

        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(IO.Path.Combine(path, file)) Then
                Dim ConStr As String = _
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
                path & ";Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;FMT=CSVDelimited\"""
                Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConStr)
                Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from " & _
                file, conn)
                da.Fill(ds, "TextFile")

            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try

        DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

    End Sub
```

Comment: So is using the OpenFileDialog the problem or passing the path to Form3 the issue?

Comment: I am hoping to get advise with both issues.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Form3 class adding a couple of global vars and force the caller of Form3 to pass an initialization value. Then use the values passed in the opening of the connection

```
Public Class Form3
    Dim mFileCSV As String
    Dim mPathCSV As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal fileCSV as String, ByVal pathCSV as String)
        mFileCSV = fileCSV
        mPathCSV = pathCSV
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form3_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       Dim fullPath = Path.Combine(mPathCSV, mFileCSV)
       if File.Exist(fullPath)  then
          .... open the connection ....


    End Sub
```

after these changes your Form1 when need to open the Form3 will call

```
   Dim of = new OpenFileDialog()
   if of.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

       .... extract file and path and pass to form3 constructor

       Dim f3 As Form3 = New Form3(file, path)
       f3.Show()
```

Comment: One minor note. `OpenFileDialog.FileName` gives you the path and file name so there's no need to separate them just to recombine them.

Comment: Yes, absolutely right, not mentioned to not distract from the main argument.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to have a button on Form 1 that opens an OpenFileDialog
>   so the user can browse for the csv file. Once the user selects the
>   file, the DataGridView and DataSet on Form 3 initiate

In order to solve this you need to do two things

**1. Use an OpenFileDialog**

This is easy. Just use the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) The below snippet adapted from the MSDN sample Opens a File Dialog box and if the

```
Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
Dim fileLocation As String
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\"
openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*"
openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True 

If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then 

    fileLocation = openFileDialog1.FileName

End If
```

**2. Pass the fileLocation to Form3**

Forms are just objects. So all the ways that you pass information from one object to another is at your disposal.

For example you could create a public property `FileLocation` on Form3 and then set it before you Show Form3. Also instead of using `Form.Load` you'd need to use `Form.Shown` instead.

Another option would be to overload the Constructor for Form3 that has a FileLocation parameter.

Comment: I placed the code in advise#1 in Form 1 and I do not have any errors and the openfiledialog box appears.  But I am struggling with Advise#2.  Could I trouble you to please post the code that needs to be placed in form 1 to pass the file location info to Form 3.  Also, could you post the code that will appear on form 3.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: @GeorgeAdis Steve was kind enough to do that already. He went an overloaded constructor. The only change you'd have to do to is make use one variable instead of two because `OpenFileDialog.FileName` give you the path and file name combined already

Comment: I am new to programming but I have finally pieced it together.  I am able to click button on Form1 and openfiledialog to import csv into Form3 datagridview while establishing DataSet.  Thank You and Steve!  One last follow-up.  If user closes Form3 window that contains the imported data, can user recall Form3 datagridview from a new Form1 Button named View?  If I place a button on Form1 named View, can I reopen form3 and view the data again?